# Find K largest elements using a priority queue

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, heaps, priority-queues, heap-sort

Say we have a Priority Queue of size 1000 that is implemented using Max Heap.

Now if i want to get the top 5 elements, the most laid back method is to poll the maximum 5 times, resulting in a set of five maximum numbers. The complexity of a poll function using heap is **Log N**. Hence, retrieving 5 top values or say, K top values will result in complexity **KLogN**.

Is there any other way of getting the top K values using priority queue with lesser complexity?

The solution [Find k maximum numbers from a heap of size n in O(klog(k)) time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/find-k-maximum-numbers-from-a-heap-of-size-n-in-oklogk-time) seems to increase the complexity rather than decreasing it, which is why i am trying to think about some other logic.  there is a sort function in the logic which will itself consume kLogk for finding one. hence say, for 5 items..it will be k*(kLogK) if K=5? hence, its not decreasing complexity.

Comment: Do you care about the order of those K top values?  Do they have to be in decreasing order?  Or do you just want the set, without regard to order?

Comment: i just want the entire set. order is not a priority. but if ordering lessens the complexity, i am fine with it as well

Comment: $k\log k<k\log N$. Why do you think the $O(k\log k)$ solution increases the complexity?

Comment: That question asks for an algorithm with $O(k\log k)$ complexity, and that's why your question is a duplicate of that question. The algorithm the OP in that question gives may not be correct, but that does not matter, because answers to that question should correct it or propose a new solution. If you are not satisfied with already existed answers, you can [make that question draw attention to our users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer), but you should not ask the question again.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that an $O(k \log k)$-time algorithm increases the complexity (from what to what?  $O(k \log N)$ to $O(k \log k)$ is a decrease, not an increase).  Basically, I can't understand the last paragraph of the question.  An $O(k \log k)$-time algorithm would be an answer to your question (i.e., a way of getting the top $k$ values with lesser complexity).  If you think this is not a duplicate, you'll need to edit the question to clarify what your question is and why that other question is not a solution, in a way that the rest of us can understand.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you don't understand how to use the hint I gave in that thread to work out a full answer to the other question.  If so, the solution is not to re-ask the question; we don't allow that here.  Instead, use the hint to try to solve it.  If you still can't, perhaps you could ask a new question where show what progress you've made , show specifically what you are stuck on, and ask a specific question about some specific aspect of the problem -- that might still be marked a dup, though.  Or, you could add a bounty to the other question to seek a better answer.

Comment: Listen, there is a sort function in the logic which will itself consume kLogk for finding one. hence, the overall complexity will be k*(kLogK). i understand your answer and have gone through it. But the logic there, is not having complexity kLogk. so i was asking if there is a solution with kLogK. and you guys marked it duplicate. if i ask another question, you guys might probably again mark it duplicate again. so no. not asking anymore here. i will work it out myself.  thank you.